# Lazy version of numpy.unpackbits

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, mmap, numpy-memmap

I use **`numpy.memmap` to load only the parts of arrays** into memory that I need, instead of loading an entire huge array. I would like to do the same with `bool` arrays.

Unfortunately, **`bool` memmap arrays aren't stored economically**: according to `ls`, a `bool` memmap file requires as much space as a `uint8` memmap file of the same array shape.

So I use **`numpy.unpackbits` to save space**. Unfortunately, it seems **not lazy**: It's slow and can cause a `MemoryError`, so apparently it loads the array from disk into memory instead of providing a "`bool` view" on the `uint8` array.

So if I want to load only certain entries of the `bool` array from file, I first have to compute which `uint8` entries they are part of, then apply `numpy.unpackbits` to that, and then again index into that.

Isn't there a lazy way to get a "`bool` view" on the bit-packed memmap file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. The memory layout of a bit-packed array is incompatible with what you're looking for. The NumPy shape-and-strides model of array layout does not have sub-byte resolution. Even if you were to create a class that emulated the view you want, trying to use it with normal NumPy operations would require materializing a representation NumPy can work with, at which point you'd have to spend the memory you don't want to spend.

Comment: Thanks! Please add a source for this info, if possible. Could rewriting NumPy help,  or are there fundamental hardware limitations? (e.g. some very low-level component not allowing to "collect" nonconsecutive bits from different places into an array)

Comment: @root: Modern computer architectures don't have bit-addressable memory, so trying to support this would be very expensive. As for sources, [here's one](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#internal-organization-of-numpy-arrays) for NumPy array representation.